# SQL Query to update a colums from a table base on a datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table called tblSetting and tblPaquets.
I need to update 3 fields of tblPaquets from tblSetting base on a where clause that use a datetime field of tblPaquest and tblSetting.

> *The sql below is to represent what I am trying to do and I know it make no sense right now.*

My Goal is to have One query to achieve this goal.

I need to extract the data from tblSettings like this

```
SELECT TOP(1) [SupplierID],[MillID],[GradeFamilyID] FROM [tblSettings]
WHERE [DateHeure] <= [tblPaquets].[DateHeure]
ORDER BY [DateHeure] DESC
```

And Update tblPaquets with this data

```
UPDATE [tblPaquets]
SET( [SupplierID] = PREVIOUS_SELECT.[SupplierID]
     [MillID] = PREVIOUS_SELECT.[MillID]
     [GradeFamilly] = PREVIOUS_SELECT.[GradeFamilyID] )
```

Here the table design

```
CREATE TABLE [tblSettings](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SupplierID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MillID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GradeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GradeFamilyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateHeure] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PeakWetEnable] [tinyint] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [tblPaquets](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PaquetID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateHeure] [datetime] NULL,
    [BarreCode] [int] NULL,
    [Grade] [tinyint] NULL,
    [SupplierID] [int] NULL,
    [MillID] [int] NULL,
    [AutologSort] [tinyint] NULL,
    [GradeFamilly] [int] NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET SupplierID = s.SupplierID,
        MillID = s.MillID
        GradeFamilly = s.GradeFamilyID
    FROM tblPaquets p CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT TOP (1) s.*
          FROM tblSettings s
          WHERE s.DateHeure <= p.DateHeure
          ORDER BY p.DateHeure DESC
         ) s;
```

Notes:

- There are no parentheses before `SET`.
- I don't recommend using `[` and `]` to escape identifiers, unless they need to be escaped.
- I presume the query on `tblSettings` should have an `ORDER BY` to get the most recent rows.

Comment: What about tblPaquets table itself?